# How do I browse the contents of a Google Cloud Storage bucket I don't own?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

The storage browser accessible by clicking `Storage > Cloud Storage > Browser` from the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) is a really convenient way to browse the contents of my buckets. However it only shows buckets owned by my projects.

Currently I want to browse the contents of a bucket to which I've been given permissions, but that is owned by a project of which I'm not a member. Is there any way for me to get the storage browser to show me that bucket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have read permission on the bucket, you can navigate directly to this URL:

https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/BUCKET_NAME/